# Which thread class except System.Threading in C# i can use in windows phone development?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there another c# class for threads, which works faster ?

Comment: if you gave an idea about what you are trying to achieve it would be more helpful as something called async programming could make your job real easy.

Comment: i begin to explore windows phone development, and i want to study about threads, i was said that there is thread class that is faster and have less functionality than System.Threading

Comment: @ Daniel Hilgarth because it has less functionality

Comment: @user967016 - If you were told this then use that.  There is nothing wrong with System.Threading.  Besides your going to be limited to whats on the Windows 7 phone and System.Threading is guaranteed to be there.

Comment: @user967016: BTW, `System.Threading` is a namespace that has a number of classes that do the same thing, you might want to specify a specific class.

Comment: @ casperOne I used Thread class, is tere faster class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are using the [`Thread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) in the [`System.Threading` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx).

Based on that, none of the classes are going to make the code that executes *on the thread* any faster; the best you can do is optimize the performance of the mechanism that you use for your situation.

That said, there are some things to be aware of:

- The `Thread` class probably has the most overhead; every time you create one, it creates a new managed thread, which might create a new OS thread.  This is not an inconsequential operation.
- Using the [`ThreadPool` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) to schedule operations *can* be faster in terms of starting your operation, as it keeps a cache of threads already created so you don't have to pay that penalty.  The trade-off here is that a) many classes in the .NET framework use the `ThreadPool` to schedule tasks, and your task will be placed in a queue; there's no way to force it to execute immediately when placed in the `ThreadPool`.
- The [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) classes in the [`System.Threading.Tasks` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx) run on top of the `ThreadPool` (this can be configured otherwise, to run with new `Thread` instances every time, for example), so you gain those benefits, but at the same time, there is overhead for cancellation, continuation, etc, etc.  You gain ease-of-use here (**much** in my opinion), with minimal overhead.

In the end, you will have to measure what is best for your application and apply that solution; like most, there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 0):

For most circumstances using your own instances of the `Thread` class is going to be slower than using work items in the `ThreadPool`.  It would take some extraordinary circumstances for you to find an advantage using the `Thread` class directly.